# Опциональные символы в маске ввода JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма, в которую нужно вводить номер банковской карты.

Сделал для нее маску через `jquery.maskedinput`.

Сама маска: `$('#card').mask('9999 9999 9999 9999');`

Но есть форматы карт и "9999 9999 9999 9999" и "9999 9999 9999 9999 999".

Можно ли сделать последние 3 символа опциональными? Если в `jquery.maskedinput` нельзя, то в какой библиотеке можно?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Как я поняла, вы используете вот этот [плагин](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput).
Идем в readme и там находим, что если перед необязательной частью поставить `?`, то все после этого знака будет опциональным для ввода.

```
$('#card').mask('9999 9999 9999 9999? 999');
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже выполнил это так: $.mask.definitions['~'] = '([0-9] )?';
$("#num").mask("9999 9999 9999 9999 ~~~");